# Which is better, "customer number" or "customer count"?

Tags: word-usage

I want to express the number of customers my company has. Is it better to use *customer number* or *customer count*?

Comment: Do you mean unique customers (different purchasers) or unique sales (number of transactions)?

Comment: By the way, customers are not *in* your company. Employees are in your company. Customers are *of* your company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid “customer number” because it is likely to be misunderstood. “Customer number” commonly refers to a customer identification number. You will be understood if you say “customer count”. Some other possibilities are “number of customers” and “total number of customers”.

Comment: As MετάEd suggested you could go with "total number of customers" or you could go with "customer total".

Answer (score 1):

You want a 'count'

> Count (noun): The result of a tally that reveals the number of items
>   in a set; a quantity counted.

Number is too ambiguous in this case, because it is usually something specific to a customer (think PIN - personal identification number) rather than a tally of the customer set.